# mixing with parameter does not work vs

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

In a SCSS sass file I used a mixin, like:

```
@mixin getHeightDueToElements($percent, $numberOfElements) {
  height: calc($percent/$numberOfElements);
  margin: auto;
}
```

SCSS and in another passage:

```
@include getHeightDueToElements(100%, 3)
```

but unfortunately it does not take me in the style css parameters with the values that I went through, and that is:

```
calc($percent, $numberOfElements)
```

This is used in all Visual study: ask is a visual studio issue, or is there something that I'm wrong?

help..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use mixings like that way you did, you should wrap in some selector or class. because you mixing is spitting attributes and properties and we can use attributes:value in some selector/s only. Hope it makes sense.

```
@mixin getHeightDueToElements($percent, $numberOfElements) {
  height: calc($percent/$numberOfElements);
  margin: auto;
}

.height{@include getHeightDueToElements(100%, 3)}
```